# Can you say which is better, DialogFragment or AlertDialog?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-dialogfragment

I know that both `AlertDialog` and `DialogFragment` are customizable. Which of the two is better? If you can say which is better, why?

Comment: if one was better than the other, why would both exist ? clearly it's situational or they do entirely different things...

Answer (score 0):

A dialog is a UI that is displayed in a window of its own. The only difference between a Fragment and a dialog is that the Fragment displays its UI in the View hierarchy of the Activity, i.e. in the Activity's window.